# Extract Twilio Whatsapp Survey Logs

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have developed a whatsapp chatbot to collect Covid19 data.

Now i want to extract the collected data into a meaningful report. The current report i can export from Twilio (twilio logs) contains data in a format which is difficult to analyze. So i wanted to create my own custom report.

I have read documentation on the following links, but cannot fully grasp how i can implement it

https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution

https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution-context

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier to capture and store the collected data at the time of entry, rather than after the Studio Flow is completed. You can use a tool like Airtable or Twilio Sync to do that. Airtable provides a built in UI to then interact with and manipulate the collected data.

Some useful blogs to look at.

[Using Airtable as a database for your Twilio app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/airtable-database-read)

[Writing to Airtable from your Twilio app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/writing-airtable-sms)

or this recent blog post which points to using Google Sheets to store data.

[Build an App without Coding: Simple SMS Survey with Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-an-app-without-coding-simple-sms-survey-with-twilio-studio)